# How to delete folders with similar names in Command Prompt

Tags: windows-10

I accidentally created thousands of empty folders on my desktop and it has essentially bricked my windows explorer.

Looking for a `cmd` prompt code to remove all of the empty folders.
They all have the number `15` at the beginning of the folder name.

They are labeled consecutively: `15 - 01`, `15 - 02`, etc.

I tried

```
for /D %f in (15*) do rmdir %f /s
```

But for each folder, the `cmd` prompt says that the

> system cannot find the specified file

despite prompting me to choose a `yes/no` on deleting the queried folder.
Thanks all, and thank you for the help

I'm using Windows 10 OS.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using CMD use Powershell.

```
Remove-Item -Path "C:\Users\[username]\Desktop\*" -Filter *15* -WhatIf
```

The `-WhatIf` will prompt to make sure you're deleting what you want and not just everything on your desktop.

If you wanted to see what the filter displays before attempting deleting, use this:

```
Get-Item -Path "C:\Users\[username]\Desktop\*" -Filter *15*
```

Answer (score 0):

Your folder names contain blanks, so you should use quotes to ensure
the folder is correctly identified :

```
for /D %f in (15*) do rmdir "%f" /s
```